# Не получается передать дескриптор дочернему процессу с помощью sendmsg

Tags: c++, unix

Передать дескриптор дочернему процессу, созданному с помощью fork(). Это можно сделать с помощью sendmsg, но у меня не получается. В чем ршибка, код ниже.

```
static
void wyslij(int socket, int fd)  // send fd by socket
{
    struct msghdr msg = { 0 };
    char buf[CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(fd))];
    memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
    struct iovec io = { .iov_base = (void*)"ABC", .iov_len = 3 };

    msg.msg_iov = &io;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
    msg.msg_control = buf;
    msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(buf);

    struct cmsghdr * cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);
    cmsg->cmsg_level = SOL_SOCKET;
    cmsg->cmsg_type = SCM_RIGHTS;
    cmsg->cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(sizeof(fd));

    *((int *) CMSG_DATA(cmsg)) = fd;

    msg.msg_controllen = CMSG_SPACE(sizeof(fd));

    sendmsg(socket, &msg, 0);
}

static
int odbierz(int socket)  // receive fd from socket
{
    struct msghdr msg = {0};

    char m_buffer[256];
    struct iovec io = { .iov_base = m_buffer, .iov_len = sizeof(m_buffer) };
    msg.msg_iov = &io;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

    char c_buffer[256];
    msg.msg_control = c_buffer;
    msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(c_buffer);

    recvmsg(socket, &msg, 0) < 0;
    struct cmsghdr * cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);

    unsigned char * data = CMSG_DATA(cmsg);


    int fd = *((int*) data);

    return fd;
}

int WS_server_worker();
void http_heandle(int size, int *fd, int client_d, int epfd);

int main()
{

    int pipe_in[2];
    int pipe_out[2];
    pipe(pipe_in);
    pipe(pipe_out);
    int fdin;
    int fdout;
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        close(pipe_in[1]);
        close(pipe_out[0]);
        dup2(pipe_in[0], 0);
        dup2(pipe_out[1], 1);
        int fd = odbierz(0);
        printf("%d \n", fd);
    }
    close(pipe_in[0]);
    close(pipe_out[1]);
    fdin = dup(pipe_in[1]);
    fdout = dup(pipe_out[0]);
    int server_d = create_socket("8000");
    wyslij(fdin, server_d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: я не спец в линуксах, но чтобы что-то принять из сокета его надо открыть, инициализаировать. recvmsg фактически вызывается для socket = 0, что он там должен получить?

Comment: ну собственно @goldstar_labs прав, родитель с дитяткой должны быть связаны `AF_UNIX` сокетом, например, возвращённым из `socketpair()`, а не трубами...